# What does this for loop do?

Tags: javascript, android

```
for (var i = RegData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();
  var title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:RegData[i].title,
    font:{fontSize:14,fontWeight:'bold'},
    width:'auto',
    top:2,
    textAlign:'left',
    left:2,
    height:16
});
```

I want the explanation of this line... and is there any alternate ways of writing this.

**for (var i = RegData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){**

Comment: The answer to *what does it do* is *just run it and see*. If that is not what you were asking, please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is initialized with one less then the length of some array(?) and it is decreased in every iteration. So instead of counting from `0` to `n` (like in a "more common" `for` loop) it counts from `n-1` to `0`. The effect is that the array is looped over in reversed order.

This can be easier written with:

```
for (var i = RegData.length; i--; ){
```

Answer (score 2):

This is using Titanium Appcelarator and is using JavaScript, not Java.

And apparently, its creating rows inside a table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to create rows in a table with title in each row.

Answer (score 1):

It apparently creates UI elements using the [Titanium framework](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/). This is however Javascript and not Java. Also, the loop is not complete (missing closing curly brackets).

Answer (score 1):

It shows the title of the Elements of RegData in a Table

Answer (score 1):

> and is there any alternate ways of writing this.

```
for (var i = RegData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    // do stuff
}
```

sure, you can write it as an while loop, if you want. Is this more clear to you?

```
var i = RegData.length - 1
while(i >= 0){
    // do stuff
    i--
}
```